ubuntu 24.04 noble numbat close all application when run some of the apps or just put it in suspend mode. did any one what is the reason for it
I am new to this platform, but I already used Ubuntu. I just installed the latest Ubuntu version one of my old laptop with the latest version. I also installed the above packages. Now when I suspend and reopen the Ubuntu it just closed all applications whatever I opened or just become stuck and can't move anywhere. I need to logout and re-enter the password to get into normal life. I don't know why this issue occurred. I just installed some of the new packages for setting the OS look cool. I don't know whether it is the problem or any other issue.

My system details:
   model: Lenovo Lenovo G50-80
   memory: 12.0 GiB
   processor: Intel Core i3
   disk capacity: 1.3TB
My software information:
   OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
   OS Type: 64-bit
   GNOME Version: 46
   windowing system: Wayland
   kernel version: Linux 6.8
for setting up Ubuntu I just installed all the below things.
Update & Upgrade:
sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade

Install Favorite Apps:
sudo apt install vlc gimp gparted synaptic

Install Ubuntu Restricted Extras (Media Codecs):
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Install Timeshift Backup Tool:
sudo apt install timeshift

Install Preload:
sudo apt install preload

Improve Laptop Battery:
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw

Just run the above command and you don’t need to do anything else. It’ll make your laptop battery last longer by implementing some power-saving protocols.
Firefox Tweaks:
about:config
layers.acceleration.force-enabled
gfx.webrender.all
Change DNS:
8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
2001:4860:4860::8888,2001:4860:4860::8844
Install Tweak Tool:
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool

GNOME Extensions:
sudo apt-get install gnome-browser-connector
https://extensions.gnome.org/
Numix Icons:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-circle
Papirus Icons:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:papirus/papirus
sudo apt update && sudo apt install papirus-icon-theme
Synaptic Package Manager:
sudo apt install synaptic:

Bleachbit:
sudo apt install bleachbit


What is your question exactly? ubuntu 24.04 noble numbat close all application when run some of the apps or just put it in suspend mode. - It is very unclear to me what you are asking

iam an new to this platform . but i already used ubuntu.i just install latest ubuntu version one of my old laptop with the latest version. also i installed the above packages. now when i suspend and reopen the ubuntu it just closed all applications what ever i opened or just become stucked and  cant move any where. i need to logout and re enter the password to get into normal life. i dont know why this issue occure. i just installed some of the new packages for setting the os look cool. i dont know whether it is the problem or any other issue. please help me

Identify the culprit: Uninstall one-by-one everything you installed until the crash no longer occurs.

Just repeating your confusing question does not clear it up.

i just reinstall the ubuntu. i do as like you said. but it not make any changes. so i reinstall it. now it going smooth. but i couldnt find which one make this problem

I'm having the same issue. When I close the lid and later unlock the system, all my previously opened programs are closed. I haven't noticed a consistent pattern—it seems to happen randomly.
